# importing ECDSA PEM key into browser for signing

Tags: javascript, cryptography

I'm trying to sign a string literal in the browser using an imported ECDSA key. Import via paste or upload I'll tackle that later. I found a library SubtleCrypto that appears to do the job but I get a DOM exception when following their example.

The key I'm using is a prime256v1 ECDSA key. This is the code I'm using per the example on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey

```
const pemEncodedKey = `-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
base64PrivateKeyHere
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----`
const pemHeader = "-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----";
const pemFooter = "-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----";
const pemContents = pemEncodedKey.substring(pemHeader.length, pemEncodedKey.length - pemFooter.length);
const binaryDerString = window.atob(pemContents);
const binaryDer = this.str2ab(binaryDerString);

console.log(await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
  'pkcs8',
  binaryDer,
  {
    name: 'ECDSA',
    namedCurve: 'P-256',
  },
  false,
  [ 'sign' ],
))
```

Where am I going wrong?

Edit: add str2ab function

```
function str2ab(str) {
  const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
  const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}
```

Comment: Where is the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: And what does `str2ab` do here? That seems to *encode* the given input string. You've just decoded it, right? It is already binary.

Comment: added the `str2ab` function for reference

Comment: seems to be a problem importing prime256v1 and secp384r1 pkcs8 keys.  only secp384r1 jwk works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was importing regular PEM file. a PKCS8 PEM file is slightly different and can be converted with:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in tradfile.pem -out p8file.pem
```

as per the documentation here

```
https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Elliptic_Curve_Operations
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting back, you can accept your own answer after about 48 hours.